# How to capture 0db frames using USRP B200?

Tags: signal-processing, xbee, zigbee, receiver, usrp

I am working on zigbee light link(ZLL) profile. I would like to capture the frames in ZLL using USRP B200. In ZLL there are frames called Inter-PAN frames, there frames will be transmitted in 0db(zero gain) only. I tried to capture those by placing the receiver close proximity to bridge. But i was unable to capture those inter-PAN frames. Other frames i captured.

How to capture 0db frames using USRP B200?

Comment: what does "transferred in 0db" mean? I've got no idea what you mean?

Comment: transmitting with zero gain.

Comment: ? That just means the transmitter didn't use any gain – so these things might just be weaker, but you don't say how much gain the transmitter has for other frames...

Comment: for other frames, gain is about 60. That's why i was unable to capture the 0 gain frames(inter-PAN). Even with close proximity also i failed. So i was searching for any other approach to capture those frames which are transmitted with 0 gain.

Comment: ok, that means a dynamic range of 60dB + dynamic range within a frame, which is pretty much. You might need to increase the receive gain of the B200 to see these frames; a common method to be sure you can "see" them at all is making a spectrogram of a recorded signal, and see whether you see the power difference between no inter-pan frame and a frame that's present

Comment: tested with maximum gain, but no use.